# C# to stored procedure error trapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In an C# mvc app I am using a stored procedure to pass multiple values back to the database.

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC ......
    , new SqlParameter("@NameTitle", sessionValues.Employee.Title.OrDbNull())
    , new SqlParameter("@Initials", sessionValues.Employee.Initials.OrDbNull())
    , new SqlParameter("@Forename", sessionValues.Employee.Forename.OrDbNull())
    , new SqlParameter("@MondayStart", sessionValues.WorkPattern.MondayStart.NullDT())
```

The context for orDbNull and NullDT

```
public static class MyClassOrDbNull
{
    public static object OrDbNull(this string s)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? DBNull.Value : (object)s;
    }

    public static object NullDT(this DateTime? x)
    {
        return !x.HasValue ? DBNull.Value : (object)x;
    }
}
```

I'm getting some stack overflow errors and because this stored procedure passes in about 50 parameters its very hard to work out what the issue is.

One issue is getting an

> arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar

which I think is an issuing passing null for the MondayStart date section. The stored procedure will accept a null though.

Commented that out and then get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Error converting data type nvarchar to tinyint.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error converting data type nvarchar to tinyint.

Is there anyone to better trap these to expose what parameter is failing on?

Comment: Any stack-overflow that is happening is unrelated to the methods shown. The code shown also doesn't do any type conversion between arithmetic and text... I'm guessing the "arithmetic overflow" is related to data contents coming back from your query, but *we can't see that data*. We can tell, from the signature of `NullDT`, that `MondayStart` is a `DateTime` or `DateTime?` - how is `@MondayStart` declared in your stored proc? if it is `datetime`, then that isn't the problem.

Comment: "is there anyone to better trap these to expose what parameter is failing on?" - what makes you think the problem is parameters? The fact that it is a `SqlException` suggests it is inside the proc - could be related to bad TSQL (parsing the `@Initials` as an integer, for example), or could be related to bad data **inside** the database, i.e. an `nvarchar` column that contains strings that are usually integer-like, but that can also be `'Fred'`

Comment: Check the store procedure is there any where clause between different column type , this is definitely a DB error.

Comment: Tip: any message that mentions `nvarchar` is coming from the SQL Server; .NET *doesn't deal in nvarchar* - it deals in `String`. So you need to look at the sproc, not (just) the C# code. Of course, it is also possible you're simply *passing invalid values* to parameters, but we can't see the declarations, most of the additions, or the actual values being passed, so *we can't diagnose that* (but: you can)

Comment: Hi and thanks, I agree the issue is passing in and invalid value to the Sql proc.  What I was hoping for was a way to identify which parameter is the issue so i can compare it.  The date time ones for example are sate to be date = null in the proc however seem to fail when passing them in in the code

Comment: use `try catch` blocks in your SP.

Comment: in try catch, check stacktrace or use exception.ToString() , it will give the detail about the exact exception..

Comment: I use try catch throw in the sp, how to i capture that in c# try catch?  not really used it as new to c#